# How to find the even numbers between a range using recursion?

Tags: c#, recursion

I am having trouble using recursion. I want to print and add the even numbers between a given range of two numbers. E.g: Range is between 3 and 9. So the output should be: 4+6+8=18.

```
printSeries(3,9);
Console.WriteLine("=" + sum);
int sum = 0;

            int printSeries(int number, int number2)
            {
                if (number < 1)
                {
                    number = 1;
                }
                if (number2 < number)
                {
                    if (number % 2 == 0)
                    {
                        return number;
                    }
                    return number + number % 2;
                }
                else
                {
                    int num = printSeries(number, number2 - 2);
                    Console.Write("+" + num);
                    sum += num;
                    return num += 2;
                }
            }
```

UPDATE:
The output I'm getting is correct, but when both numbers are odd, there is an extra iteration. E.g: Range is 3,9: 4+6+8+10=28.

Answer (score 1):

I don't your target exactly but I test your code and then change your code in second section

```
 private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // PrintSeries(7, 13);
        PrintSeries(2, 8);
        Console.WriteLine("=" + sum);
        System.Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static int sum = 0;
    private static int PrintSeries(int number, int number2)
    {
        if (number < 1)
        {
            number = 1;
        }
        if (number2 <= number)
        {
          if (number % 2 == 0)
            {
                return number;
            }
            return number + number % 2;
        }
        else
        {

            int num = PrintSeries(number, number2 - 2);
            Console.Write("+" + num);
            sum += num;
            return num += 2;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This code is working on odd numbers perfectly but, now the problem is that when a number is already even, it is adding one number less like: 2,8 = 4+6+8=18. I want it to be 2+4+6+8=20.

Comment: Please check again

Comment: There is one extra iteration if both numbers are odd, now.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not behind the system.

Comment: Please can you check again later?

Comment: Oh yeah, l can check about 4 hours later

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201154/discussion-between-gracefulfantasy-and-behroz).

Answer (score 0):

```
 string str="";
 int sum=0;
 Void printSeries(int number, int number2)
        {

          for(int i=number;i<=number2;i++){
          if(i%2==0){
            sum += i;
            if(i!=number){
                str += "+"+i; 
            }else{
                str += i;
            }                
          }
          }
          Console.WriteLine(str + "=" + sum);
          printSeries(7,13);

       }
```

Comment: I asked "using recursion"

Comment: @GracefulFantasy: To what end? This is not a problem that requires recursion to solve. Are you asking about homework?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
public int SumOfEvenNumbersInRange(int start, int end, IList<int> elements)
{
    int CreateSum(int current, int sum)
    {
        if (current > end)
        {
            return sum;
        }
        else
        {
            elements.Add(current);
            return sum + current + CreateSum(current + 2, sum);
        }
    }

    if (Math.Abs(start) % 2 == 0)
        return CreateSum(start, 0);

    return CreateSum(start + 1, 0);
}
```

This uses a local function to do the actual recursive work.
You can then use it like this:

```
var elements = new List<int>();
var sum = SumOfEvenNumbersInRange(7, 13, elements);

if (elements.Count == 0)
{
    elements.Add(0);
}

Console.WriteLine($"{string.Join(" + ", elements)} = {sum}");
```

Using it like above would print the following:

```
8 + 10 + 12 = 30   // SumOfEvenNumbersInRange(7, 13, elements)
2 + 4 + 6 + 8 = 20 // SumOfEvenNumbersInRange(2, 8, elements)
```